# how to construct a homeomorphism between $T$ and $S$?

Tags: general-topology

$S=\{x^2+y^2\le 1\}$, $T=\{|x|+|y|\le 1\}$, could anyone tell me how to construct a homeomorphism between $T$ and $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We can consider both $S$ and $T$ in $\mathbb C$ as $S=\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ and $T=\{z:z=a+ib,|a|+|b|\leq 1\}$, then define $f:T\rightarrow S$ by $f(x)=re^{i\theta},$ where $r$ is the unique $r\in [0,1]$ such that $x\in \{z:z=a+ib,|a|+|b|=r\}$, and $\theta$ is the argument of $x$.